# Salesforce Marketing Cloud Connector User Permission

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

Hello and Happy Holidays,
I need to give access to a Business Partner to allow them to configure our Salesfore Marketing Cloud connector.
What level of access do they need in the Salesforce Cloud and Salesforce Marketing Cloud?
 
Cheers,
M

Comment: Marketing Cloud Administrator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to provide an Administrator Tracking user for both Marketing Cloud and your Sales Cloud.

For your Business Partner to configure, they will need administrative access to configure the connector and Contact Builder.

If you are concern around security etc. they you could restrict them from sending emails, Users etc - but this becomes a real hindrance when configuring / troubleshooting etc. If you trust your Business Partner and have proper NDAs and security checks in place, then give Administrative Access. Alternatively, have your business partner sit with your system administrator to go through the configuration